Adding .Net Aspire to Existing Blazor Server App
I have a Blazor Server .Net 8 web application.  I right-click on the Blazor sever project and select "Add" then ".Net Aspire Orchestrator Support".
This added the two Projects (AppHost, and Service Defaults) to my solution. The AppHost project is selected as the start-up project.  When I run the app in Debug mode it fails and I am getting the below-attached error.
Any idea what is wrong? It seems it's trying to convert a string to a boolean.
When I debug my app normally without using Aspire, I use IIS Express in  Visual Studio
If it helps this is the full error msg
System.Text.Json.JsonException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]. Path: $.profiles.DptBlazor.dotnetRunMessages | LineNumber: 27 | BytePositionInLine: 33.
  Source=System.Text.Json
  StackTrace:
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader, Exception ex)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.ContinueDeserialize(ReadBufferState& bufferState, JsonReaderState& jsonReaderState, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.Deserialize(Stream utf8Json)
   at Aspire.Hosting.LaunchProfileExtensions.GetLaunchSettings(IProjectMetadata projectMetadata)
   at Aspire.Hosting.LaunchProfileExtensions.GetLaunchSettings(ProjectResource projectResource)
   at Aspire.Hosting.LaunchProfileExtensions.TrySelectLaunchProfileFromEnvironment(ProjectResource projectResource, String& launchProfileName)
   at Aspire.Hosting.LaunchProfileExtensions.SelectLaunchProfileName(ProjectResource projectResource)
   at Aspire.Hosting.LaunchProfileExtensions.GetEffectiveLaunchProfile(ProjectResource projectResource, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at Aspire.Hosting.ProjectResourceBuilderExtensions.WithProjectDefaults(IResourceBuilder`1 builder, Boolean excludeLaunchProfile, String launchProfileName)
   at Aspire.Hosting.ProjectResourceBuilderExtensions.AddProject[TProject](IDistributedApplicationBuilder builder, String name)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\Dpt.AppHost\Program.cs:line 3

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'String' as a boolean.



Im using IIS Express when I run it without Aspire and it works fine.  But when I try and use Aspire i get the error
My launchSettings.json is below, im using Windows Auth:
  {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/DptBlazor",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

After cleaning up launchSettings.son I got it to run a bit more, but now I get an odd error.






My launching settings file is below:
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61105",
      "sslPort": 44392
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost/DptBlazor",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    },
    "DptBlazor": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    }
  }
}

Below is the code im using to get the Windows Authentication User Name, which seems to come back blank:
private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider authProvider;
       var authenticationStateTask = await authProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

   var user = authenticationStateTask.User;

   if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
       return user.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1]; ;
   }


Have you added anything to appsettings.json file ?

@ChinmayT,  Hiya, nope I have not added anything to the appsetting.json file, should I have?

Have you added 'builder.AddServiceDefaults();' into the startup.cs of Blazor Server Application ?

Normally this error occurs when JSON is generated with "" as value instead of the null element.

@ChinmayT:  Yes I checked my program.cs and I have the below
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.AddServiceDefaults();
The only other thing I can think of is that I run my app under a specific url (as i need the app to run under a specific service account) such as:
https://localhost/DptBlazor
As opposed to:  https://localhost:3336/    (using port number)
Could this be a factor

Below is the only other thing I noticed that is added to Program.cs file when I add a ".Net Aspire Orchestrater  Support" to my Solution.
app.MapDefaultEndpoints();
I am assuming this is okay?

Yes, that's okay. I believe it has to do with the launcher profile. Do you have any specific launcherProfile settings defined into your webapp "dptBlazor" ? if yes, then in AppHost project's startup.cs at line 3 change it to "builder.AddProject<Projects.DptBlazor>("dptBlazor", "launchProfileName")"

I am adding my sample application setting. I have launcherProfile with "http" and "https" names.  My AppHost looks like this.builder.AddProject<Projects.AspireAppTest_Web>("webfrontend", "http")
//.WithEnvironment("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Development")
.WithOtlpExporter()
.WithExternalHttpEndpoints()
.WithReference(apiService);

@ChinmayT:  thanks ever so much for the comments. I cleaned up my launchSettings.json file (see above) and started to get better results.  Aspire loads but then it errors when I run the DptBlazor app, see attached screen shot where its trying to load localhost:5000 which is odd as my app is configured to use localhost/DptBlazor.  Many thanks for all your help.  I think we are getting closer

@ChinmayT:  it seems that on my Aspire dashboard my endpoint is blank, see attached screen shot

We are close to solve this. Have you added "builder.AddProject<Projects.DptBlazor>("dptBlazor", "IIS Express")" This will link the profile and application url.

@ChinmayT:  Yes I added that line (see attached), but it say the service "failed to start", if I dont put in a "IIS Express", Aspire starts but it tries to start the app on port :5000 for some odd reason.  Any other ideas?

I have found the fixed for your issue. I was having an app which was using IIS Express and I have added Aspire support on it and start getting the same error which you were getting. I have updated my launchSetttings.json little bit to get this work.

This solution works for a Blazor Server application running with "IIS Express" profile and .Net Aspire Orchestrator Support added later on. This will generate an error message something like below when you first run your Aspire.host project with "https" profile.

To resolve this error, you need to update launchSettings.json file of your original Blazor server project. Go to BlazorServerApp.UI project > Properties folder > expand it and open launchSettings.json file. It will look like something below.
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61105",
      "sslPort": 44392
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "BlazorServerApp.UI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true" 
    }
  }
}

Change the line from "dotnetRunMessages" : "true" to "dotnetRunMessages": true. This is the bug from Asire framework. This will start your project but will show you an empty or "None" endpoints on Aspire Dashboard. See user's question screenshot above.
Add below two lines into your "IIS Express" profile.
 "applicationUrl": "https://localhost/blazorserverapp",
 "dotnetRunMessages": true

This will fixed the problem and start showing you your newly entered endpoints into Aspire Dashboard. The final launchSettings.json will look like below.
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61105",
      "sslPort": 44392
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      //below lines added manually
    //"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44392",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost/blazorserverapp",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    },
    "BlazorServerApp.UI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      //Changed below line manually from "true" to true
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    }
  }
}

In Aspire.Host, I have to changed back to builder.AddProject<Projects.BlazorServerApp_UI>("blazorserverapp-ui"); without mentioning the "IIS Express".
If you are getting "failed to start" error on Aspire Dashboard then follow below two steps.

Close Solution and Close Visual Studio
Delete ".vs" folder from solution path
Reopen VS and your solution.
Run the Aspire.Host

It should start and Aspire Dashboard will start showing below Endpoint registered.

Let me know this works for you or not. I have to update my packages to the latest version for everything to workout well. Make sure you are not using Visual Studio Preview version.

This is amazing, you are a star!  I get an error when I try and Multiple Start Up Projects when Debugging and having solution not only load the .AspHost but also my Blazor app.  See attached screen shot I added for the error.

I am using Aspire.Host as my startup project. I launch my BlazorServerApp by clicking on Endpoint URL from Aspire Dashboard. I am not sure why you are start both of the projects as multiple startup projects.

Ahh I see what you mean, I dont need it to be a multi startup.  But I have hit another issue when I click the web link in Aspire, the Windows Authentication does not seem to work, see attached screen shot and my lanchSettings.json
Thanks ever so much for your support

Try right click on it and open it in incognito mode. It might be because of the browser cache. I have my window authentication working with this.

I tried incognito, still no joy.  I have posted above what I have on my page of how I get the Windows Authentication User Name, it always assumes the user is not authenticated.

Were you able to get a Username when you are using Windows Authentication in IIS?  I still cant seem to get it to work

Yes, Windows authentication was already working before adding Aspire and After adding Aspire also it's working fine without any issue.
